# What's the most efficient way to render a template that changes based on primary key of a table (Django)

Tags: django, django-views

I am creating a search page where users can search by parameters. The search parameters change based on the category they are searching in. There are approximately 100 categories and each has its own unique search parameters.

Currently I have an if statement in the view that checks 100 categories and then renders one of 100 corresponding forms, but I feel it's not efficient. What is the most efficent/best way to do this?

Currently I think something like this

```
if category.id == 1:
    # RENDER FORM1
elif category.id == 2:
    # RENDER FORM2
elif category.id == 3:
    # RENDER FORM3
....
```

Comment: Can you add some code to have an idea of what is going on on your view?

Comment: Why should I add code for the sake of adding code? This is a 'most efficient way' type of question and I think I explained it well?

Comment: Also why did I get downvoted? Where's the love SO? If there's a better place to post this type of question, please let me know.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted you, and I asked about code because for example I have some doubts, do you have 100 FORMS? Or just a form that can be generalized, if is the latter, I will love to see the form, also at first I didn't know about category.id. In fact is very ugly to have a hundred if statements and a hounded forms so that's why I asked, still I haven't enough info to imagine how to render those hundred forms :(

Comment: @user1328021 Probably because there's not enough information to answer the question as-is, and your reaction to Paulo's request (which makes sense) likely encouraged someone to downvote you. How are these forms different? How can we generalize that? We can't answer those questions without more code.

Comment: Thanks @PauloBu ... that makes sense actually. I haven't written all the forms yet but they all have different fields. There is some overlap but not a lot. Let me think of how I can explain that better.

Comment: I think some forms can be generalized -- ie. there are some common fields, but others are unique for a particular category (ex: manufacturer). If I create one mega form though, I would still need the if statements on the template side to determine which fields to display, right?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Ok, sorry that came out the wrong way. It was more of a philosophical question that went awry,

Comment: I wrote an answer that might help a little, specially with the `if` conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna give an answer here that may simplify the problem a little. If you actually have almost 100 forms and need to code them all. Maybe you may declare some sort of global dictionary or array and at the end of each form definition, include them in it, for example:

```
# a dict this way category.id -> form class
FORM_STORAGE = {}


Form1(forms.Form)
   #fields
   #methods
FORM_STORAGE[1] = Form1

Form2(forms.Form)
   #fields
   #methods
FORM_STORAGE[2] = Form2

...
```

Then in your views you might receive a `GET` parameter which is exactly the category that needs to be rendered so instead of:

```
if category.id == 1:
    # RENDER FORM1
elif category.id == 2:
    # RENDER FORM2
elif category.id == 3:
    # RENDER FORM3
....
```

you can do something like:

```
   # RENDER FORM
   form = FORM_STORAGE[category.id]()
```

And there you have reduced your views in a hundred or more lines of code.

This is a very simplified version of the problem, it is quite possible that can be done more improvements, specially in the declaration of the hundred forms.

Hope this bring some light.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks that makes a lot of sense and I never thought of that!

Comment: Just say a form reuses the same parameters as another form. Is there a way to make optimizations there?

Comment: I don't know, I've never stumbled with the need to code so many forms. Are forms representing objects? What's the variation between them?

Comment: The forms are basically to get user input for searching. It's to conduct an "advanced search" on each category. So they can search in the "Shirt category" and then hone down by "color = red, type = long-sleeve, etc." and then the "Pants category" people could hone down by "color = blue, length = 36 inches" , for example. So a field like color could be shared, but not the others...